# How to Define Second and Third Orthogonal Basis Vectors with Respect to First Basis Vector?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors, definition, orthogonality

I have defined my first normalized basis vector, which is {f}, now I want to define the second basis vector {s} somehow that is orthogonal to the {f} and then define the third basis vector {k} which is orthogonal to {f} and {s}. I was wondering, is there any method or formulation in linear algebra for this type of definitions?

Thank you in advance for any help anyone might be able to provide.

Comment: [Gram-Schmidt process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process)

Comment: @angryavian, thank you for your reply, but in this method, you should have the second and third basis vectors to orthogonal them with respect to each other, but unfortunately, I only have the first basis vector and doesn't have any clue about the second and third basis.

Comment: Choose some arbitrary vector that is not a scalar multiple of the first vector, and apply Gram-Schmidt to get the second vector orthogonal to $f$. Then choose some arbitrary vector that is not a linear combination of the first $f$ and $s$, and then apply Gram-Schmidt to get your third vector $k$.

Comment: If you happen to be working in $\mathbb R^3$, you can obtain a third vector that is orthogonal to the first two by taking their cross product.

Comment: @angryavian, thank you very much for this help. I am new to this type of definitions, and I will be thankful if you could share a simple example with me.

Comment: yes, @Bungo, I am working in a three-dimension euclidian space, thank you for this hint.

Comment: We know that $f$ is not zero.  If one component of $f$ is zero, change it to $1$ to get $s$.  If no component is zero, change an arbitrary component to $0$ to get $s$.

Comment: Dear @Micheal Hoppe, thank you for your answer; I tried your method, but {s} is still not orthogonal to the {f}. I should mention that none of the components of {f} is zero. If I change one of the components of {f} to zero, can this new vector be an arbitrary vector for {s} and I use the Gram-Schmidt process to orthogonal it to {f}?